# Teach enemy that the way thru screen border is shorter than going all over the screen

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a project, a little game, where I have integrated some things I learned from answers to my previous questions. Well, I wanted to make a title screen. Everything worked fine, but in the "game" I integrated the "wraparound-effect", that means the player gets off the screen one side and comes in the opposite. My version of that effect is pretty simple, because of that, the monsters can't follow the player thru the screen border and walk all over the screen, that makes the game much simpler, and that's not what I want it to be.

Can I teach the enemies to follow the player thru the screen border?

Here's the code:

```
#sorry if the code isn't perfect, please just answer my question :) (you don't have to rewrite it)
#enemy means devil, I first did not want to make more enemies.
import pygame, time, math
pygame.init()

display_width = 1300
display_height = 700
win = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
Icon = pygame.image.load("Enmy.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(Icon)

playerimg = pygame.image.load("Playr.png").convert_alpha()
imgsize = (57, 100)
playerimg = pygame.transform.scale(playerimg, imgsize)

enmimg = pygame.image.load("Enmy.png").convert_alpha()
imgsze = (57, 100)
enmimg = pygame.transform.scale(enmimg, imgsze)

slimeimg = pygame.image.load("slime.png").convert_alpha()
imgesize = (57, 100)
slimeimg = pygame.transform.scale(slimeimg, imgesize)

gameover = pygame.image.load("GameOver.png")
imgsz = (100, 100)
gameover = pygame.transform.scale(gameover, imgsz)

player = playerimg.get_rect(center = (650, 350))
vel = 3

enemy = enmimg.get_rect(center = (650, 600))
EnemyVel = 2.7
DevilLives = 1

slime = slimeimg.get_rect(center = (650, 100))
slimeVel = 2.3
slimeLives = 1

Gameover = gameover.get_rect(center = (350, 350))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0))
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def Intro():
    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            intro = False

        win.fill((255, 255, 255))
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Monster Run", largeText)
        mediumText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",40)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects("Press SPACE to start", mediumText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(150))
        textRect.center = ((display_width/2),(670))
        win.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        win.blit(textSurf, textRect)
        win.blit(playerimg, player)
        win.blit(enmimg, enemy)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(15)

def game():
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(50)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

        collideDevil = player.colliderect(enemy)
        collideSlime = player.colliderect(slime)
        cldDevlSlm = enemy.colliderect(slime)
        if cldDevlSlm:
            enemy.x = enemy.x + 20
            slime.x = slime.x - 20
            
        if collideSlime:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
        if collideDevil:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
            
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        player.x += (keys[pygame.K_d] - keys[pygame.K_a]) * vel
        player.y += (keys[pygame.K_s] - keys[pygame.K_w]) * vel
        player.x += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * vel
        player.y += (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * vel

        #wraparound-effect
        if player.x <= -40:
            player.x = player.x + 1300
        if player.x >= 1300:
            player.x = player.x - 1340
        if player.y <= -40:
            player.y = player.y + 700
        if player.y >= 700:
            player.y = player.y - 740

    #devil "AI"

        dx = player.x - enemy.x
        dy = player.y - enemy.y
        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
        if dist > 0:
            enemy.x += min(EnemyVel, dist) * dx / dist
            enemy.y += min(EnemyVel, dist) * dy / dist

    #slime "AI"
        Dx = player.x - slime.x
        Dy = player.y - slime.y
        Dist = math.hypot(Dx, Dy)
        if Dist > 0:
            slime.x += min(slimeVel, Dist) * Dx / Dist
            slime.y += min(slimeVel, Dist) * Dy / Dist
                
        win.fill((255, 255, 255))
        win.blit(enmimg, enemy)
        win.blit(playerimg, player)
        win.blit(slimeimg, slime)
        pygame.display.flip()

Intro()
game()
```

Comment: would be great if you provided a [mre], about the solution, one way seems to be that you measure the distance between player and the closest border to the enemy, if the border is closer than the player move there (maybe set some threshold how close the border has to be too so that the enemy doesn't start walking to the border when it is almost in the middle of the map because it would look a bit weird IMO) and go through, else go after the player across

Comment: OK, but I dont know how I should do that... I not that good in python, because I just started with it. Oh, and thanks for editing my question. Wait... I think I understand. I will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the modulo (`%`) operator to simplify the code that "wraps" the player around the screen:

```py
player.x %= 1340
player.y %= 740
```

"Invert" the movement of the enemy, if the distance between the enemy and the player is greater than half the width respectively half the height:

```py
dx = player.x - enemy.x
dy = player.y - enemy.y
w = 1340
h = 740
if dx > w/2:
    dx -= w
elif dx < -w/2:
    dx += w 
if dy > h/2:
    dy -= w
elif dy < -h/2:
    dy += h
```

Finally "wrap" the enemy around the screen:

```py
enemy.x %= 1340
enemy.y %= 740
```

---

[image]

Minimal example:

```py
import pygame, math

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = pygame.Rect(250, 150, 20, 20)
vel = 5
enemy = pygame.Rect(50, 150, 20, 20)
enemyVel = 3

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.x += (keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] - keys[pygame.K_LEFT]) * vel
    player.y += (keys[pygame.K_DOWN] - keys[pygame.K_UP]) * vel
    player.x %= (window.get_width() + player.width)
    player.y %= (window.get_height() + player.height)

    dx = player.x - enemy.x
    dy = player.y - enemy.y
    w = (window.get_width() + player.width)
    h = (window.get_height() + player.height)
    if dx > w/2:
        dx -= w
    elif dx < -w/2:
        dx += w 
    if dy > h/2:
        dy -= w
    elif dy < -h/2:
        dy += h 
    dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
    if dist > 0:
        enemy.x += min(enemyVel, dist) * dx / dist
        enemy.y += min(enemyVel, dist) * dy / dist
    enemy.x %= (window.get_width() + enemy.width)
    enemy.y %= (window.get_height() + enemy.height)

    window.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 0, 255), player)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), enemy)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: Thank you! Are all of those things on your github site?

Comment: @PhoenixAnton The [PyGameExamplesAndAnswers](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers) repository is just a collection of Stack Overflow answers.